# rsync over ssh, gets permission denied

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, permission-denied

I gonna backup some files from a local machine to a remote server trough rsync over ssh. Here is the command I used:

```
rsync -avh -e  "ssh -p 3286" somelocal_folder/ me@x.x.x.x:/data/bu/
```

The user(me) which I use to ssh to the server has rwx permissions on /data/bu directory but it does not have write permission on /data. It raises permission denied error when I enter my password. I searched a lot in the Internet,but I could not find any thing relevant. Any idea of the cause of the problem?!!

Comment: Have you confirmed that `me@x.x.x.x` can write a file into `/data/bu/` (by logging in and using `touch`, for instance)?  I want to rule out forgetting to give search permission on `/data` or something like that.  It may be helpful to post the result of running `ls -ld /data /data/bu` on the server.

Comment: Yes, me@x.x.x.x can write into /data/bu/ . The results of ls -ld /data /data/bu is as follows: drwxrwxr-x+  5 root  root  /data
drwxrwxr-x+ 26 me root  /data/bu/. me@x.x.x.x has search permission on /data.

Comment: Actually,  I changed the permission on /data to drwxrwxr-x, and it works. But I don't want to give "me" write permission on /data, I want it to only have rx permissions(drwxr-xr-x for /data). Is there a way to work around this problem without escalating privileges?

Comment: @Alex can you post the error message?

Comment: @Alex - interesting (read: baffling!).  So changing `/data`'s g+x bit directly determines the success?  I really didn't expect that.

Comment: Can you successfully `rsync` a small file to `/tmp`?  Just wondering if the remote end is executing a misbehaving `~/.bashrc` or something...